# Center align buttons inside Float:left div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have 3 left aligned floats. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sydg5rzt/1/)'s the following JFiddle that does it.

```css
div { height: 45px; }
div.side {
    background-color: skyblue;
    width: 72px;
    float: left;
}
div#range {
    background-color: tomato;
    width: 216px;
    float: left;
}
span {
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 3px auto;
    /* background-color: gold; */
}
```

```html
<div id="start" class="side">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<div id="range"></div>
<div id="end" class="side">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do now is center align the buttons within the div called side. I've tried using another div with it's text-align set to center, but that doesn't work.

Comment: horizontal or vertical?

Comment: @AkulVonItram Horizontal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text-align: center` applied to `.side` divs should do the trick, because `button` elements are inlines by default.  Note, I changed `.side`'s widths to make the centering effect noticeable: https://jsfiddle.net/021gu79c/1/.

CSS:

```
div.side {
    background-color: skyblue;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
}
```

Comment: if I also wanted to center it vertically, while keeping the text-align:center property working, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess he means horizontal, based on the text-align property.

Hav you tried to add a wrapper div around the Buttons with

```
.btn-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  left:40%;
  right:40%;
```

Maybee that's working for you

Comment: I did mean horizontal alignment. I tried what you said, and the outcome looks like this... https://jsfiddle.net/sydg5rzt/14/

Comment: Ok looks like it's working fine. Just the Buttons on the blue background not. I can't prove it right know but it seams to be beacause of the width, you set in the css for the container.